# Declare size of an array at Runtime

Tags: java, arrays

I'm coding a program that copy the contents of all the files to the last input file taken( all the files are given by the user at Command prompt). So, how can I declare an array that takes the size from the user?

Comment: `String filenames[] = new String[lenghtTakenByUserFromConsoleWhichIsValidInteger];`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it like that:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  <-------- import the class

public class InputFromUser { 

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);    
        System.out.println("Enter a number for the array size:");
        int size = scan.nextInt();    
        int[] arr = new int[size];

    }

}
```

Either use `java.io` like this:

```
BufferedReader columnInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
int size = Integer.parseInt(columnInput.readLine());
```

Comment: Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  What does it mean?

Comment: It's a Java Class that helps you get input from the user `System.in`.
please look on the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't use it. is there any other way?

Comment: you need to import this class, please look at my updated code

Comment: Actually, I meant I can't use this package. The only package I'm allowed to use is java.io. Any other way around?

Comment: @Akshay if you think that this is the correct answer for you, please mark it using the `V` beside it

Answer (score 0):

If the list of files supplied when running the application as arguments : you can use the args.length property which returns the number of the supplied arguments:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args.length);
}
```

Comment: This doens't answer the question in any aspect.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ The question is highly ambiguous.  I think this is a good answer, but chenchuk has interpreted the question differently from how you did.  I think it's a mistake to punish the respondent for answering a poorly worded question.

Comment: Why not ? the list of files provided by the command line as arguments, this should be the array size ... isnt it the question ?

Comment: @DavidWallace  Which part of the question you didn't understand? The user will provide the files at the command prompt!

Comment: @chenchuk I think it is pretty obvious the asker meant console command prompt from console java application, rather the JVM command line arguments.

Comment: @DavidWallace Benefit of doubt :) I removed my downvote. . At least justifying explanation for why to use `args.length` will be good.

Comment: @Akshay Who said I didn't understand it?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do in this way :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
      System.out.println("Enter a array size:");
      int arraysize = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
      int[] arr = new int[arraysize];

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```